# how does a TypeLoadException Happen?

Tags: .net, types, typeloadexception

```
public sealed class SurrogateSelector : System.Runtime.Serialization.SurrogateSelector, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISurrogateSelector
{
    System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializationSurrogate ISS = System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSurrogateForCyclicalReference(new SerializationSurrogate());
    public SurrogateSelector()
    {
        foreach (Type t in typeof(NameSpace.ASampleClass).Assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (t.Namespace == "NameSpace")
                this.AddSurrogate(t, new System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContextStates.All), ISS);
        }
    }
}
```

> {System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException:
>   Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.    at
>   System.Reflection.Module._GetTypesInternal(StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() 
>   at NameSpace.SurrogateSelector..ctor()
>   in
>   D:\Projects\Esfand\Esfand\classname.cs:line
>   2661}

Comment: the "NameSpace" is in the same module(the procedure is in that namespace)

Comment: What's the exception message?  Is there an InnerException?

Comment: it would be helpful if you show entire code

Comment: Follow the instructions and retrieve the `LoaderExceptions` property for more information.

Comment: @João Angelo:it says that the problem is with RVA(i have lots of externs) but why should that stop the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that all externs are correctly defined. The CLR will be unable to load the types if it cannot find the implementation for the external methods you defined.

For example if you define a method like,

```
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr w, uint m, IntPtr p1, IntPtr p2);
```

make sure that you use the `[DllImport("user32.dll")]` on it. Each `TypeLoadException` should tell the method for which no implementation was found.